# ASP.NET MVC3: Problems with forms, not showing my field values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

For the sake of validation, I decided to try using the `@Html.TextBoxFor` so that validation is quick and easy. However, there is not an option to set the value, and I assume it's done automatically, but it isn't being automatically set.

Controller:

```
        MyLibrary.MyProspect prospect = MyLib.GetProspect(ID);
        return View(prospect);
```

View:

```
@model MyLibrary.MyProspect

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Prospects"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit</legend>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

My library defination of Prospect:

```
public class MyProspect
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

My guess is that at no point do I set the model to actually be my prospect. But no examples I have come across do this, and I assume I pass it from view as I have?

**SOLVED**
This is working code, Id just mixed and matched my controller action to the wrong view.

Comment: Is the problem that the textbox is empty when viewed in the browser?

Comment: Have you checked with debug if the values ​​are returned on GetProspect?

Comment: the values are all fine, I origionally used a normal text box. and populated it with the given option. `@Html.TextBox("Name", (String)ViewBag.Prospect.Name)` And yes, the textboxfor is empty

Comment: Your code look right. In your comment you write about ViewBag?? Thats a totally different story.

Comment: Yes, thats the old way< Im trying to change it to use textboxfor, and hence the model. My point there was that the getprospect method is definately working.

Comment: Could you show your entire controller action?

Comment: Thanks Darin, you made me realise my mistake. For some silly reason Id gone and set no model in the relevant controller and infact had written it in the View action! It wasnt till I copied View i thought hang on, this code isnt for my edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For client side validation to work there are a couple of things you need to do:

1. Decorate some fields in your model using the appropriate [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)
2. Ensure you have the `ClientValidationEnabled` & `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` options set to `true`. This can be done directly in the `<appSettings>`.
3. Include the appropriate libraries in the page i.e. `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`

Also if you have no special view requirements you could reduce your code to:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Comment: using `@Html.EditorForModel()` , All 12 fields have boxes for them, yet all 12 are blank. is the instance of the prospect correctly set? I'll try the 1-3 things you mentioned.

Comment: Bit silly what Id done really, Mix and matched the wrong action and view. But thanks a ton for the new bit of code, I like neat :)

Comment: No problem :) If you do need to customize your view and you want to still stick with the `EditorForModel` approach, you can create custom templates - see http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html for a good tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have written looks correct, I would guess your problem is in MyLib.GetProspect(ID) not setting the value of the Name field.

Comment: This is definately not the case. Successfully show it on screen using `@Html.TextBox("Name", (String)ViewBag.Prospect.Name)` Where `ViewBag.Prospect = prospect`. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

`@model MyLibrary.MyProspect` This line sets your model to be MyProspect.

Do you have DataAnnotations on your MyProspect.Name property?

Maybe adding your definition of MyProspect.Name to you question would help as well.

Comment: Added to question. That line `@model MyLibrary.MyProspect` sets the model to MyProspect, but it doesnt say that the instance it is using is `prospect`?

Comment: @Doomsknight - Well done - an easier way to check if you have the right data in your model than using viewbag, is to use the @Model (notice the capital M) and just do `<span>Name is @Model.Name</span>` and that gives you the value without it being dependant on an HTML Helper.

Comment: Cheers, that will save me a headache next time! Never thought to do it.